# Intersection of two spheres and a plane

Tags: geometry

I want to know the coordinates of the two points where two spheres and a plane intersect.

Sphere 1: $(x-a)^2$ + $(y-b)^2$ + $(z-c)^2$ = $78.8^2$

Sphere 2: $(x-d)^2$ + $(y-e)^2$ + $(z-f)^2$ = $78.8^2$

Plane: y = ${b-e\over c-f}$$(z)$ + b - $(c)$${b-e\over c-f}$

Where [a, b, c, d, e, f] are known

How do I find these two coordinates in terms of the known values [a, b, c, d, e, f]

Comment: Just to add some geometrical intuition to this problem so the answer has some geometric meaning. There is a case where the 2 spheres and the plane are all tangent to each other (the plane is squeezed in between the spheres) in which there is 1 solution. There is another case where the 2 spheres overlap and the plane intersects the 2 spheres, in which the solution is a portion of the plane. Finally there is the case where the 2 spheres overlap and the plane is tangent to the area of overlap, where there is 1 solution. Otherwise there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

The short, only slightly facetious answer is: solve the system of equations.

One approach is to subtract the equation of one sphere from the other to get the equation of the plane on which their intersection lies. Intersect this with the other plane to get a line. If you parameterize this line and then substitute into either sphere equation, you’ll end up with a straightforward quadratic equation to solve.